# Can't convert this text in normal format in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, fonts

I am web-scraping some stuff and i got something like this "735    , ,  02122 Dorchester MA 02121" how do i convert it to normal text in python?

Comment: You should be able to just grab the plain text from the html while web scraping, unless the website itself is using other characters to give a font effect rather than tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run it through [Unicode normalization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

```
import unicodedata

unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', '735    , ,  02122')

# '735 William T Morrissey Blvd, Dorchester, MA 02122'
```

Here's a REPL screenshot that demonstrates it works:

[image: NFKD]

Answer (score 0):

Using native python:

```
def normalise(a):
    newstr = ''
    for i in a:
        if 120458<=ord(i)<=120483:
                newstr+=chr(ord(i)-120361)
        elif 120432<=ord(i)<=120457:
                newstr+=chr(ord(i)-120367)
        else:
                newstr+=i
    return newstr
```

Output:

> a = "735    , ,  02122 Dorchester MA 02121"

```
>>> normalise(a)
'735 William T Morrissey Blvd, Dorchester, MA 02122 Dorchester MA 02121'
```